# Calculating R, C & maximum input current of Oscillator Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, feedback

I have been trying all day to understand how either one of the values C1, Rs2 or the maximum input current can be initially calculated. I have worked out the equations however it seems that there is no obvious starting point, every equation needs a value of either Rs2, C1 or the maximum input current. What value can be determined first? I think it might be the maximum input current, but again I can't seem to find a solution. I have read on a few forums that the audio range oscillates typically around 0.25uF to 0.25mA in a standard oscillator. So I could use 0.25mA, but that isn't a very accurate design method, since surely the maximum current is dependant to the circuit design. Any ideas? would it[image] have something to the with the TL084 data sheet ?

Design Specs:
Frequency Range: 20Hz - 2000Hz
Voltage range of V7: 0v - 5V

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this should oscillate?

Comment: Take a look at the unity gain point  [phase margin] and the large swing Vout vs R load at 200 Ohms being 50% and what is this current and phase shift with 1nF at f= same f for unity gain where phase margin goes to zero.  If you reduce C1 then it will be more stable.  Iin must not exceed I out limit or cause significant phase shift or else it becomes more unstable. (i.e. less phase margin)

Comment: Im not sure, what would this need in order to be an oscillator?   Also, will I find that inform in the data sheet or an I looking at the phase margin of the circuit (sorry bit of a beginner) ? thanks

Comment: Could you explain that in a  bit more detail ? Im not sure what I am looking for